# Loosing line break when uploading document to google drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api

When uploading my document to google drive I loose my line breaks. When uploading the document as a text file it works:

```
    ByteArrayContent content = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", body);

    File uploadedFile =  drive.files().update(
            file.getId(), file, content).setSetModifiedDate(true).execute();
```

But when i add setConvert(true) to upload the file as a Google document I loose the line breaks.

```
    ByteArrayContent content = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", body);
    File uploadedFile =  drive.files().update(
            file.getId(), file, content).setConvert(true).setSetModifiedDate(true).execute();
```

I have tried to add different types of line breaks to my string (eg '\r', '\n' and even tried to use both). Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So I have found out that my insert of a new file works. It is when I do an update of the file content that I loose my linebreaks.
This is my insert and it works.

```
  ByteArrayContent content = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", body);
  drive.files().insert(file, content).setConvert(true).execute();
```

This is my update. Now I loose my line breaks.

```
  ByteArrayContent content = ByteArrayContent.fromString("text/plain", body);
  File updatedFile =  drive.files().update(
            driveFile.getId(), driveFile, content).setConvert(true).execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the problem. Before updating the document I downloaded its metadata:

```
File driveFile = drive.files().get(resourceID).execute();
```

This File had mime type as a Google document. Before updating I had to reset the mimetype to "text/plain"